# Subscript out of range on the line >>> total = Workbooks("Summary File.xls").Worksheets.Count

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Double
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

directory = "c:\test\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")

Do While fileName <> ""
Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
    total = Workbooks("Summary File.xls").Worksheets.Count
    Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy _
    after:=Workbooks("Summary File.xls").Worksheets(total)
Next sheet
Workbooks(fileName).Close
fileName = Dir()
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is "Summary File.xls" open?

Comment: @Comintern yes it is open

Comment: The file name must be wrong, or it's open in a different instance of Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's because "Summary File.xls" is en Excel 97-2003 format and you are trying to insert in it worksheets coming from more recent Excel version files that has more columns and rows, thus originating an error as a consequence of which "Summary File" gets closed and subsequent attempts at referencing it (i.e. `Workbooks("Summary File.xls")`), throw that "Subscript out of Range" error

Change your "Summary File" to an at least 2007 Excel version (from scratch, otherwise attempts with Save As will generate a Compatibility mode that would still throw that error), and then run your macro

BTW, substitute `Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name)` with `sheet` inside your `For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets` loop